# How to differentiate system code version revision?

Tags: design-patterns

I have developed a product with several features.
we have released our first version v1r1 few days back.

Now we have started developing in v1r2.

My question is how can I manage v1r2 code with v1r1 ??

If I will do conditional compiling (#define V1R2) then code will become messy as there would have multiple release of this code and there may be a chance of conflicting code if team 1 is working on v1r1 and team 2 is working on v1r2 simultaneously.

I don't want to keep different copy for version revision (v1r2). I will keep different copy once we start working on v2(version 2).

Any idea will be highly appreciated.
Thanks 
-Sandeep Patel.

Comment: Is there some reason why you can't use version control and make a branch for the second version, then merge the changes into the mainline when you're ready to release it?

Answer (score 0):

I always find [gitworkflows](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitworkflows) to be enlightening. Even if you don't use Git, the practices described there are very sound and applicable to almost any version control system (although deprecated systems that don't represent the history as a DAG will possibly give you a hard time when performing the merges).

I also like [this article](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) which goes a bit more into detail. For this workflow there exists a [set of scripts](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) that make implementing this workflow much easier.